# How (this::methodName) is working in this code?

Tags: android

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739958/test-that-app-launches-another-app-in-android) there is one line,

```
findViewById(R.id.go_to_play_store).setOnClickListener(this::goToPlayStore);
```

how does this line is exactly handling the click listener ?

Comment: "goToPlayStore" is a function he calls.

Comment: read about java 8 ::operator (and lambdas)

Comment: thats power of lambda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java8 introduces concept of [Method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and [Functional interfaces](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/java-8-functional-interfaces). If function `onClickListener` requires a function with one argument(a.k.a Functional Interface) then if return types and argument types match your function(which is goToPlayStore) then you can pass its reference as functional interface.

Answer (score 2):

This is the new JAVA 8 language feature Lambda Expressions.

:: refer to a new syntax in Java 8 known as [method references](http://baddotrobot.com/blog/2014/02/18/method-references-in-java8/). You can reference a class or instance and pass along the method that will handle the event

On click its calling function called goToPlayStore () located in that activity or fragment.

Answer (score 2):

> its Method references in Java 8

Which allows us to refer to an existing method by name. Method references can be used in place of lambda expressions as long as they satisfy the requirements of the functional interface.
For static methods the syntax is

```
Classname::methodName
```